Help determining sample size without standard deviation
I need some help optimizing our website intercept survey sample sizes, but our online platform only provides us with the means (often mean of 5pt ordinal scales), sample sizes and denotes statistical significance only after the fact. We have several surveys that are triggering much too often, but in order for me to make the business case to reduce the triggering instance, I need to recommend a new sample size to aim for.
Because the software does not provide me with the standard deviations of the means, I’m taking it at its word that the changes are or aren’t statistically significant. While I believe it is true, it doesn’t help me to simulate what a lower sample size would still maintain significance. Can I do this without the SD? I know with proportion sample size calculators I can use a 0.5 proportion to widen the margin of error, is there a similar formula for means? Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Do you have anything besides the mean? With a P-value and sample size you can approximate the SE and thereby SD.

Have you considered using sequential sampling?  That does not require prespecification of a sample size and, when appropriately designed, has an expected sample size smaller than the conventional one.  It's well suited for start-and-stop operations like yours sounds to be.
